# How do I auto-mount a LUKS disk at login WITHOUT unmounting it at logout?

Tags: partitioning, mount, login, encryption, luks

So I have an external LUKS-encrypted disk connected to my machine, and I want to automatically mount it after I log in. After some Googling I found pam_mount, and it does exactly what I want, except that it automatically unmounts at logout.

So how do I keep it from unmounting itself? I don't want to add a keyfile and I don't want to have it mounted at boot, only after logging in. I guess I could add something to .bashrc but that'd be my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keys to unlock the LUKS volume at boot up. Say your LUKS volume is on /dev/xvdb1, first create /etc/crypttab with the following content

```
cblk01  /dev/xvdb1 /etc/luks-key01 luks
```

Create a key and add it to your LUKS volume

```
openssl genrsa -out /etc/luks-key01 2048
chmod 400 /etc/luks-key01
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/xvdb1 /etc/luks-key01
```

Finally add this to /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/cblk01  /data   xfs defaults 0 0
```